# Accessing virtual method from abstract class using repository pattern

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm stuck in understanding - how to access and use (or is it even possible to use) base class virtual method.

So the code is:
Base class:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public string VehicleIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public abstract string DisplayName { get; }

    public virtual bool HasAnAmazingColor(){         
    }
}
```

Repository pattern:

```
public class VehicleRepository : IVehicleRepository, ICollection
{
    private readonly List<Vehicle> _vehicles;

    public int Count => _vehicles.Count;

    public object SyncRoot => ((ICollection)_vehicles).SyncRoot;

    public bool IsSynchronized => ((ICollection)_vehicles).IsSynchronized;

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((ICollection)_vehicles).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((ICollection)_vehicles).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public VehicleRepository(List<Vehicle> aVehicles)
    {
        _vehicles = aVehicles;
    }
```

Then int unittest I try to get the virtual method, but do know that I'm not understanding something, but cannot figure out what, how can I use the method without overriding it?

```
  [TestClass()]
public class VehicleRepositoryTests
{

    private VehicleRepository vehicleList = new VehicleRepository(new List<Vehicle>());

    [TestMethod()]
       public void HasAmazingColor()
    {
        //arrange

        //act
        vehicleList.??? -- I'm missing something 

        //assert           
    }
```

I can access virtual method in any of the derived class that implements Vehicle, but is there a way to use it in repository pattern?

Comment: What method are you trying to access? `VehicleRepository` isn't derived from `Vehicle` so you're not trying to access one of its methods. I can't see any way that you've implemented which will give direct access to the `Vehicle` objects contained within the repository (other than copying them out).

Comment: I'm trying to access  public virtual bool HasAnAmazingColor().

Comment: So you need an instance derived from `Vehicle` to access one of its virtual methods, right? To spell this out as clearly as I can: `VehicleRepository` is not derived from `Vehicle`, therefore it doesn't have any methods of `Vehicle`'s base class because it is not a `Vehicle`.

Comment: Did you mean to do something like `vehicleList.FirstOrDefault().HasAnAmazingColor` since you are trying to make your repo look like a _collection_?  Note you will still need to make it a type-safe collection

Comment: Though repos have simularities to collections you shouldn't really take that as verbatim because that's what the underlying ORM provides.  A repo isn't really meant to be a `ICollection` rather something that encapsulates entity lookup; search operations and decoupling such operations from the rest of the system

Comment: Oh hang on, why are you calling it a _"respository pattern"_ when you aren't dealing with databases? Why not just change your code to `public class VehicleRepository 
 : List<Vehicle> { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have abstract base calls `Vehicle`.

From careful observation of your code, I found that you have not derived your `VehicleRepository` Class from `Vehicle`.

So you will not be able to access the virtual method from `Vehicle` on `VehicleRepository` instance.

The method you are looking for `HasAmazingColor` will be available on every single object in `List<Vehicle> _vehicles;`

May be you can expose the List of Vehicles as property and then use it in the unit test, just in case you want to use it.

Or

If your design does not allow to explose the `_vehicles` as public collection, then you can have a public method in `VehicleRepository` class which internally calls the `HasAmazingColor` method on appropriate `Vehicle` object or objects.

The solution will depend on your application design.

Comment: It is just observation.  It will be available on every single item of List.  I will update the answer to explicitly mention this.